# interval scheduling algorithm where overlap is allowed

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling

I have stumbled into a problem that looks similar to the classic [interval scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling)
However, in my case I do allow overlap between intervals- just want to minimize it as much as possible.

Is there a canonic algorithm that solves this? I did not find a 'relaxed' alternative online.

Comment: You've specified two objectives, one explicitly (minimize overlap), one implicitly from the interval scheduling problem (maximize intervals chosen), but haven't stated how to prioritize them.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, I have a bunch of jobs that need to run at a certain time window. No matter what. Assume I know the execution times in advance.

But I want to space them out in a way that minimizes execution overlap (to reduce concurrent resource consumption).

Comment: Does the execution time vary from job to job?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat yes.

Comment: Does it increase when there is significant overlap between intervals?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, no, at least I don't think so. Today everything happens all at once and while each job spins its own cluster- there can be slowdown associated with IO throttling. but I don't think it is significant.

For practical purposes, it is safe to assume the intervals are different but constant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this problem maps cleanly to any of the classical scheduling literature. I'd try to solve it as an integer program using (e.g.) [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization).

What makes this problem hard is that the order of the jobs is unknown. Otherwise, we could probably write a dynamic program. Handling continuous time efficiently would be tricky but doable.

Similarly, the natural first attempt for a mixed integer programming formulation would be to have a variable for the starting time of each job, but the overlap function is horribly non-convex, and I don't see a good way to encode using integer variables.

The formulation that I would try first would be to quantize time, then create a 0-1 variable `x[j,s]` for each valid (job, start time) pair. Then we write constraints to force each job to be scheduled exactly once:

```
for all j, sum over s of x[j,s] = 1.
```

As for the objective, we have a couple of different choices. I'll show one, but there's a lot of flexibility as long as one unit of time with `i + j` jobs running is worse than one unit with `i` jobs and a different unit with `j` jobs.

For each time `t`, we make a non-negative integer variable `y[t]` that will represent the number of excess jobs running at `t`. We write constraints:

```
for all t, -y[t] + sum over (j,s) overlapping t of x[j,s] ≤ 1.
```

Technically this constraint only forces `y[t]` to be greater than or equal to the number of excess jobs. But the optimal solution will take it to be equal, because of the objective:

```
minimize sum over t of y[t].
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am thinking about it.